# Reverse Proxy Apache and Team Foundation Server

Tags: apache, security, iis, proxy, reverse

Someone have implemented a server Apache as reverse proxy to connect to Team Foundation Server 2010?

I have a few problems with configuration file of Apache. The IIS response don't send the credentials request.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting the following configuration as a reverse proxy apache with  TFS:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mytfsserver.com
   KeepAlive On
   AllowCONNECT 80
   ProxyPass / http://tfsserverhostname:8080/    timeout=10 ttl=10
   ProxyPassReverse / http://tfsserverhostname:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems to be a good configuration but if you leave the connection by disconnecting your browser from tfs and another user try to connect to tfs (http://www.mystfsserver.com/tfs) has direct access without giving username and password as the first connected user